# Why for loop runs twice when called using numpy.vectorize in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I have the below function that I want to call on a column of a dataframe.

```
    def remove_pattern(input_text, pattern):
        r = re.findall(pattern, input_text)
        print("r:", r)
        for i in r:
            print("i:", i)
            input_text = re.sub(i, '', input_text)
            print("input:", input_text)
        return input_text
```

Added print statements for my understanding.

I call it just the first row instead of the full column just to test the functionality:

```
    total['tidy_tweet'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(total['tweet'][0], '@[\w]*')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
r: ['@user']
i: @user
input:   when a father is dysfunctional and is so selfish he drags his kids into his dysfunction.   #run
r: ['@user']
i: @user
input:   when a father is dysfunctional and is so selfish he drags his kids into his dysfunction.   #run

​
input_text OR `total['tweet'][0]` = "@user when a father is dysfunctional and is so selfish he drags his kids into his dysfunction.   #run"
```

As per my understanding, it should run just once. Also, I understand that numpy's vectorize function works like a loop on the column. I would appreciate it if someone can help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `vectorize` makes one call to the function to determine the return `dtype`.  It then calls the function once for each scalar element of the input.  Read about `otypes` if you want to avoid the initial call.

Comment: @hpaulj: thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the assumption that Python is a slow, despite coder-friendly, language. So NumPy doesn't use Python under the hood. Citing its home page:

> The core of NumPy is well-optimized C code.

NumPy's Github repo can confirm this, a third of the code is written in C, there are even Fortran pieces! A general approach to working with numerical computing is to **avoid for-loops** (i.e. switching to slow Python) and try to do as much as possible using functions from your library of choice. This applies to PyTorch and TensorFlow as well.

Pandas is built on top of NumPy, and also has great [built-ins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html) to manipulate strings: `str.replace`, `str.exctract` and so on.